# Spark SQL's where clause excludes null values

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run queries on Apache spark sql. The first query works fine, but the second query removes null values also.

code  :

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Spark")
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val pageViewsDF = getDataframe(sc, sqlContext)

    println("RUNNING SQL QUERIES ")

    sqlContext.sql("select name , count(*) from pageviews_by_second group by name").show(10)

    sqlContext.sql("select name , count(*) from pageviews_by_second where name not in (\"Rose\") group by name").show(10)

  }

  def getDataframe(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext): DataFrame = {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);

    val dataArray = List(List("David", null),
      List("David", null),
      List("Charlie", "23"),
      List("Rose", null),
      List("Ben", null),
      List("Harry", "43"),
      List(null, "25"),
      List(null, "21"),
      List("David", "15"),
      List("Rose", null),
      List("Alan", "26"))
    val separator = ","

    // Create an RDD
    val dataRDD = sc.parallelize(dataArray)

    // The schema is encoded in a string
    val header = "name,age"

    // Import Spark SQL data types and Row.
    import org.apache.spark.sql._

    // Generate the schema based on the string of schema
    val schema =
      StructType(
        header.split(separator).map { fieldName =>
          StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)
        })

    val rowRDD =
      dataRDD
        .map(p => Row(p(0), p(1)))

    // Apply the schema to the RDD.
    var df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)

    df.registerTempTable("pageviews_by_second")

    df
  }
```

The result of first query is  :

```
+-------+---+
|   name|_c1|
+-------+---+
|   Alan|  1|
|    Ben|  1|
|  David|  3|
|Charlie|  1|
|   Rose|  2|
|  Harry|  1|
|   null|  2|
+-------+---+
```

And the out put of second query :

```
+-------+---+
|   name|_c1|
+-------+---+
|   Alan|  1|
|    Ben|  1|
|  David|  3|
|Charlie|  1|
|  Harry|  1|
+-------+---+
```

In the second query I am excluding "Rose" only but "null" is also getting excluded .

If my query is wrong please help me with the correct query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens because `NULL` in SQL is equivalent to "unknown". It means that any comparison with `NULL`, other than `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL` is undefined and returns `NULL`.

```scala
case class Record(id: Integer, value: String)

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(Record(1, "foo"), Record(2, null))).toDF
df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql("""SELECT value = "foo" FROM df""").show
// +----+
// | _c0|
// +----+
// |true|
// |null|
// +----+

sqlContext.sql("""SELECT value != "foo" FROM df""").show
// +-----+
// |  _c0|
// +-----+
// |false|
// | null|
// +-----+
```

Because of that `IN` / `NOT IN` is undefined as well:

```scala
sqlContext.sql("""SELECT value IN ("foo", "bar")  FROM df""").show
// +----+
// | _c0|
// +----+
// |true|
// |null|
// +----+
```

This is a standard SQL behavior and system that correctly implements SQL standard should behave the same way. If you to filter and keep `NULLs` you'll have to make it explicitly:

```scala
sqlContext.sql(
  """SELECT value IN ("foo", "bar") OR value IS NULL FROM df""").show
// +----+
// | _c0|
// +----+
// |true|
// |true|
// +----+
```

Comment: Thanks , answer is very helpfull , but how my where clause should look like to get null values too in result ?

Comment: See the last snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch back in the two state logic you need to  `coalesce` the nullable column (this is the standard term for proprietary `NVL`) to some non existing value.

Using same setup as @zero323

```
 sqlContext.sql("""SELECT value, coalesce(value,'other baz') = "foo" FROM df""").show
```

.

```
value c1
foo   true
null  false
```